# Bootstrap columns with stacked images: need to have same column height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap section with stacked images and the issue is that I want the second and third columns to always have the same height as the first column. I can't seem to find a solution for the second and third column because they keep fluctuating in height as I change to different view sizes. It would be ideal to have them always align to the bottom and top.

```css
.gallery {
 min-height: 980px;
}
  
.gallery .row{
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid gallery">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
       <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/528/980/technics" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/409/490/technics" class="img-responsive"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/409/490/technics" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/324/327/technics" class="img-responsive"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/324/327/technics" class="img-responsive"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/324/327/technics" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Here is the Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/mb2Ez6G7r8

Comment: Did you try adding `a { display: flex; }`?

Comment: So you want them always to be the same height as the **first column**, even if the first column is smaller or bigger that the others?

Comment: xpy: Correct. Although in this situation, the first column will always be bigger/taller.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Patrick. I already tried that and when I shrink to smaller viewports, the columns don't stay the same height.

Comment: With the column widths being different and the image widths not fitting them exactly this could be very difficult. If you make the image widths divisible by 12 with heights that correspond exactly, it might work.

Comment: I think the closest you will get is setting the image widths as 516, 407 and 298. Loose the flex and min height. It will be a couple of pixels out at some sizes but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Paul you can resolve in that way, i see that you use boostrap you dont need the property flex in your css.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
   <a href="#"><img src="https://www.jssor.com/demos/img/paint/01.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.jssor.com/demos/img/paint/02.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/409/490/technics" class="img-responsive"></a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.jssor.com/demos/img/paint/06.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

and your css

```
.gallery {
min-height: 980px !important;}
```

dont forget add bootrap in your html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

i explain why you dont need flex, Boostrap make your thml responsive with class .row and you can fill this with 12 columns that is why you have col-sm-(Number) in your case 5+4+3=12 if you want you can read more in this link [grid systemn](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 0):

```
.column-sm-4{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

If height is an issue you should probably use `background-image` with css instead of `<img>` element.
Hope this will solve the issue.